# Should replace be done in mysql or php?

Tags: php, mysql, replace

To reduce the size of downloaded data I would like to replace some repetitive sections of the data with a code, reconverting on the client.

Should the replace be done within the mysql query or after in PHP, or does it matter?

Within mysql:

```
SELECT IF(SUM(val)=16,0,CONCAT("[",GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ".000" FROM val) ORDER BY itm),"]"))
```

PHP:

```
$q=str_replace("1.000","1",$q);
$q=str_replace("[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]","0",$q);
```

Comment: what do you mean downloaded data? I encourage you to skip these kind of manual cpu operations and instead, enable GZIP on your apache server.

Comment: then be sure you benchmark your changes because there's most chance that it doesn't do anything but adds up precious cpu overhead

Comment: what about performances? You could use the audit module of chrome to compare before/after (f12)

Comment: Seems to take about 20-30% longer to compile the smaller data set.

Comment: yeah, and what kind of real performances gain do you have in terms of transfer speed? That's the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever you choose to do it, do not do it inline. Contain it in a function so you can reuse and manipulate the logic without breaking the actual query and vice versa.

I'd use my vote for PHP code because when you switch to somethingElseDB tomorrow you won't need to figure out to implement the same logic on an entirely different SQL syntax. I think PHP implementation is also easier to read.

Comment: Placing the code in a mysql function (routine) Slowed down the query. This was due to the routines being in a separate database (required to serve multiple databases), not sure why this would slow them down.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will be faster than PHP and will keep your code a bit cleaner.